# Tensorflow concat while training different shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

hei guys, i will as about how to concat tensor object with own definition tensor object while training, I'm training autoencoder model.

this is my code:

```
def IFFT(sig, name=None):

    nol = tf.zeros([1,12],tf.complex64)
    pv = tf.fill([1,8],3+3j)
    pv = tf.cast(pv,dtype=tf.complex64)
    nol = tf.expand_dims(pv,axis=1)
    pv = tf.expand_dims(pv,axis=1)
    return Lambda(lambda x : tf.ifft(tf.concat([nol,x,pv,nol],axis=-1)), name=name, output_shape=(1,64))(sig)
```

while i running that code i have error

```
InvalidArgumentError: ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [1,1,12] vs. shape[1] = [64,1,32]
     [[{{node 32-IFFT/concat}}]]
     [[{{node loss/add}}]]
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: as the error says, the numbers in first two dimensions must be same for both the arrays. You need to make dimension 0 match (currently they are 1 and 64)

Comment: i see, 64 because my batch size is 64 too. but if i access the sig.shape()  it's say [?,1,32]. how can i know the value of "?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to handle batching is to create a variable named **BATCH_SIZE**, and manually input the desired **batch size of your data**. This is typically done if you are doing custom operations where None batch size may not work for you or you need more control for the data.

I reproduced your code and **assumed** the **shape of your X variable** (1, 32) as it is not included in your code snippet.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print('TensorFlow Version : {}'.format(tf.__version__)) # Using TensorFlow 2.1.0

BATCH_SIZE = 64

nol = tf.zeros([BATCH_SIZE,1,12],tf.complex64)
pv = tf.fill([BATCH_SIZE,1,8],3+3j)
pv = tf.cast(pv,dtype=tf.complex64)

#Assuming your data X based on your error
x = tf.zeros([BATCH_SIZE,1,32],tf.complex64)

# Verification 1
tf.signal.ifft(tf.concat([nol,x,pv,nol],axis=-1)) 

# Verification 2
tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x : tf.signal.ifft(tf.concat([nol,x,pv,nol],axis=-1)), output_shape=(1,64))(x)
```

This is a common approach when dealing with **Batched Data**, as it is **easier to be referenced** and to be **more consistent** throughout the code.

*Modified Code:*

```
BATCH_SIZE = 64

def IFFT(sig, name=None):

    nol = tf.zeros([BATCH_SIZE,1,12],tf.complex64)
    pv = tf.fill([BATCH_SIZE,1,8],3+3j)
    pv = tf.cast(pv,dtype=tf.complex64)

    return Lambda(lambda x : tf.ifft(tf.concat([nol,x,pv,nol],axis=-1)), name=name, output_shape=(1,64))(sig)
```

Comment: thanks, it works for me, just need a little bit tuning on my dataset length